# Dynamic connecting/disconnecting signals and slots

Tags: qt, optimization, signals, slot

My program has two states and it can switch between them for some reasons. In these states the program needs to receive different signals, which means it has to connect and disconnect certain signals during the run.

How bad is such approach?

Comment: By "two conditions", do you perhas mean "two states"?

Comment: @hyde Yes. Probably states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fine approach, I've used it before without issues. Depending on what you're actually doing a [`QSignalMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsignalmapper.html) might be of use for you.