# Signal flow drag and drop like Simulink in Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt

**Situation**: I have a lot of algorithms in ANSI C and want to connect them dynamically

**Idea**: Creating a Simulink type of Canvas to dynamically drag/drop and connect the algorithms and check for correct inputs. So i have blocks to connect with a "line" which symbols the signal (i.e. the numerical data).

**Question**: Is this possible with Qt and what would be a good example/starting point to begin with? I have to change signals/slots from different classes (the algorithm blocks) while runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you want is called data flow programming. You can certainly develop a graphical application with Qt that will allow you chaining your computational blocks together.
Take a look on a similar idea discussion [on qt forum](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/18959/).

Comment: Thanks for the term **data flow programming**. It's always good to know what other people call what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can not change the singals and slots during runtime, but the connections can be changed easily via connect and disconnect. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15274147/dynamic-connecting-disconnecting-signals-and-slots) might also be interesting for you.

Comment: Or, to elaborate: it's possible to add signals/slots at runtime, but that's by using totally private APIs (i.e. the ones QML uses!). Take a look at [QMetaObjectBuilder](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobjectbuilder.cpp.html).